# Triple integral over a three dimensional region

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, 3d

The integral $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{x^2}^4\int_0^{1-y/4} 1\ dz\ dy\ dx$$is a triple integral over a three dimensional region E,  Sketch E, and rewrite this integral with $y$ as a first variable and $z$ second variable and $x$ as a third variable.

What I have done so far:

[image]

$0\le z \le{1-y/4}$

$x^2\le y \le+4$

$-2 \le x\le+2 $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your picture looks excellent - nice work.

Now, to switch the order of integration, we will be integrating in the $yz$ plane first then integrating over $x$.  So, we need to think about what $yz$ slices of our region look like.  Key observation: they are triangles: 
[image]

I've labelled all the key points of interest; we first fix $x$, which gives us a triangular cross section.  Then, we fix $z$ and vary $y$ (the horizontal line). Its first point of contact with the solid is at $y=x^2$.  It leaves the solid when $y=4-4z$ (i.e. when it hits the surface $z=1-y/4$).  These are your $y$ bounds.  Finally we must vary $z$ within the triangle - it starts at $0$, and ends at the "top" vertex of the triangle.  There, $y=x^2$, so we have $z=1-x^2/4$.  Thus we have:

$$
\int_{x=-2}^{x=2}\int_{z=0}^{z=1-x^2/4}\int_{y=x^2}^{y=4-4z}1dydzdx
$$

The general strategy is to fix the last variable, then work over the cross section formed by the other 2 variables.  Hope this helps!